# Why is the Asset Pipeline re-compiling compiled assets, creating redundantly nested paths?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

When I deploy my app to the production environment (using capistrano), I have been getting an error during asset pre-compilation:

```
  * executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  * executing "cd /home/ubuntu/projects/Marketplace-web/releases/20130124162353 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile"
    servers: ["server_name"]
    [server_name] executing command
*** [err :: server_name] rake aborted!
*** [err :: server_name] File name too long - /home/ubuntu/projects/Marketplace-web/releases/20130124162353/public/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/assets/widgets/jquery.jcarousel-d505e569ed1040e0b45bc33e0e49f117.js-26b4b41e4a45cb353ba7e39510893ace-93b194138c96579222ca08f9651946a7-43eca25d0cc511b37176bc58d8575e1a-1b97916c47bfa22545013b3751cb59e4-d9043106773924d12596e08b349f00dc-b7b7aa9bf440ca19896b1103d7651728-c40c1f2b8b11e6de163fefea9db6778c.gz+
```

I found a comment on http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=comments , saying the issue can be solved by removing this from my config/application.rb:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/public"
```

I removed it, and the task stopped re-compiling my pre-compiled, static assets in the public/assets folder, but my question is: Why was it doing that in the first place?  Isn't that config line intended to tell Rails where to find my other, non-compiled, static assets?  Why would it be trying to compile assets in the config.assets.paths array?  Don't I need that line so Rails knows where to find my static assets?

Am I doing it all wrong?  Where should I be putting my non-compiled, static assets and how should I tell Rails where to find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the [Rails Assets Configuration Documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets):

- `config.assets.paths` contains the paths which are used to look for assets. Appending paths to this configuration option will cause those paths to be used in the search for assets.

Do not add the *output* directory to the array of *input* directories. Otherwise, the output of the previous assets-compilation run will be included as yet another input into the next assets-compilation run.

Your compilable assets should typically be in `app/assets` if you wrote them or `vendor/assets` if you didn't. Why not put `jquery.carousel.js` into `vendor/assets/javascripts/`?

Comment: Ooh, thank you! So even if an asset doesn't require any compilation or translation by the asset pipeline, I still have to run it through the asset pipeline rather than just storing it in the public directory?  I guess I could see that, that just wasn't clear to me before... is that right?

Comment: The asset may not require compilation from one source language to another destination language, but it is still useful ti use the asset pipeline anyway.